# Escape special characters in snowflake procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, escaping, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create function that will generate SQL code minus defined column.
Issue is with `'` character which damages entire code by giving error:

> `unexpected 'SELECT'. syntax error line 2 at position 94 unexpected 'as'.`

Nested SQL works with no issues, nesting it into a UDF is where the issue is.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_SQL_TBL_MINUS_COL(tbl varchar, col varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS

$$
SELECT 'SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY_AGG(c.column_name),',') || ' FROM ' || c.table_name as STMT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.table_name = tbl  --table name
AND   c.column_name NOT IN(col) --column name
GROUP BY c.table_name;
$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

`c.table_name` must be excluded from `GROUP BY` and replace by `tbl` in

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_SQL_TBL_MINUS_COL(tbl varchar, col varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
AS

$$
SELECT 'SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY_AGG(c.column_name),',') || ' FROM ' || tbl
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.table_name = tbl  --table
AND   c.column_name NOT LIKE (col) --column
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't like the GROUP BY. It indicates something other than a scalar value is resulting from the UDF, which is not allowed. This compiles:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_SQL_TBL_MINUS_COL(tbl varchar, col varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS

$$
SELECT 'SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY_AGG(c.column_name),',') || ' FROM ' || c.table_name as STMT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.table_name = tbl  --table name
AND   c.column_name NOT IN(col) --column name
--GROUP BY c.table_name;
$$;
```

Although it compiles, I'm not sure it's what you want. If this isn't getting you there let me know and I can help modify the UDF.

Comment: SELECT GET_SQL_TBL_MINUS_COL('TABLE', 'COLUMN') results in error: `SQL compilation error: [C.TABLE_NAME] is not a valid group by expression`

Comment: Indeed. I'll check on that.

Comment: I found solution ;)

Comment: Please post if you have a minute. Thanks.

Comment: Done, have a look :)